# Trying to get property of non-object when username is incorrect using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using password_verify to check the password is correct or not which is working perfectly. My issue is when the user entered the wrong username clicked on login button than I am getting the error that `"Trying to get property of non-object"`.

Instated of error it should display the validation error message.

If I enter the correct username and wrong password than I am getting the proper validation error message(Password is invalid) but If I enter the wrong username and correct password then I am getting the error `"Trying to get property of non-object"`.` 
Would you help me out in this?

**Controller**

```
public function login_user()
 {

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_password_database');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  $this->load->view('login');
}
else
{
  //redirect(base_url('Student_controller/index'),'refresh'); 
}

 }

 /*Checking the login details*/
function check_password_database($user_password)
{
    $a_username=$this->input->post('user_email');
if (empty($a_username)) {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('check_password_database','Email is Invalid');
}
else{
   $password_fetch=$this->access_model->password_fetch($a_username);
   if(password_verify($user_password, $password_fetch))
    {
     redirect('Student_controller/index','refresh'); 
    }
    else{
       $this->form_validation->set_message('check_password_database','Password is Invalid');
       return FALSE;
  }
}
}
```

**Model**

```
public function password_fetch($username)
{
        $query=$this->db->select('emp_password')
                ->from('employee_info')
                ->where('emp_email',$username)
                ->get();
$result = $query->row();  
return $fetch_pass=$result->emp_password;

}
```

Comment: where does the error occur? The error message tells you that, so please tell us, too. On a side note, you shouldn't tell the user what part of their credentials is wrong. When you tell them the email is wrong, a malicious user can bruteforce many emails until you tell them the password is wrong. Then they know this email is a valid email in your system. Give them a unified message instead.

Comment: I am getting the error message on the view page(login).

Comment: The error message doesn't say "Trying to get property of non-object" on view page (login). Please include the complete error message.

Comment: @Gordon, The above error is the complete error. Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: models/Access_model.php
Line Number: 27

Comment: And which line in your shown code is line number 27?

Comment: @Gordon,this is the code on line no 27. return $fetch_pass=$result->emp_password;

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to access an array directly. Between `$a_username` and `$password_fetch` one must be a array which you are directly trying to access.

You must echo both of them to find how values are stored in them.Try printing them with `echo $a_username;die;` and similarly for the other.

If it is an array try printing `echo "<pre>";print_r$(a_username);`
Also initialize `$fetch_pass=""` in model;

Answer (score 0):

Change your model

```
public function password_fetch($username)
{
        $fetch_pass = false;
        $query=$this->db->select('emp_password')
                ->from('employee_info')
                ->where('emp_email',$username)
                ->get();
        $result = $query->row();  
        if (isset($row) && ($row > 0)) {

                $fetch_pass=$result->emp_password;
        }
        return $fetch_pass;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, If any user entered the wrong email than error goes off. but if any user entered the correct email and wrong password than I am getting the error Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int
Filename: models/Access_model.php
Line Number:36

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
return $fetch_pass = $result->emp_password;
```

without validating if `$result` is actually an object. If the user does not exist, the `$result` will not be an object. Consequently, trying to fetch `emp_password` when `$result` is not an object, will give you the error message *Trying to get property of non-object*.

Do this instead:

```
if (isset($row)) {
    return $result->emp_password;
}
```

Further reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

On a side note, [an application should respond with a generic error message regardless of whether the user ID or password was incorrect. It should also give no indication to the status of an existing account.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Authentication_and_Error_Messages)

Comment: Yes, It's working. I just want to know. in case the username is wrong than can we display the error message that username is invalid?

Comment: @NarendraVerma you can, but you shouldn't. See the linked OWASP guide in my answer.